# How to fix inverse normls of a point cloud?

Tags: opengl, point-cloud-library, cgal, normals

I have a point cloud and want to generate normals of each point. For now, I have tried multiple methods.The normals I generated look right but has two possible directions,towards inside or outside the models,and there is no consistance rule to control it.
So is there any method that can generate reliable normals? Thank you!

Here is a sketch of my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given a triangle defined by its three vertices ABC the vector perpendicular ("normal") to this triangle is easyly obtained with the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two vectors, for example ABxAC. But also ABxBC.

The point here is that cross product is NOT commutative. So, ABxAC is not the same as ACxAB. Exactly it is ABxAC = - ACxAB, this is, **the same vector but heading the opposite direction**.

A normal heading out the *front face* must be calculated according to the [winding order](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling#Winding_order) or the triangle. The same order you set the triangle vertices in the buffer is the order to choose the vectors for the cross product.

You must be aware of how GL makes winding order depending of the type of [triangle primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)

EXAMPLE

Let's say you use glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, ...) and your vertices buffer looks like v1,v2,v3, v1,v3,v4, v1,v4,v5, etc (vi= vix,viy,viz) where all winding orders are counter-clockwise. Then:

```
Vector AB = v2 - v1
Vector AC = v3 - v1
Vector perp = cross(AB, AC)
Vector norm = normalize(perp) //divide each component by lenght of perp
```

Now you have normal to faces, the normals at points is a bit tricky.

The simplest way is calculating the average of the normals to the triangles sharing the vertex. When each fragment of the triangle is shaded, the normal at that point may be interpolated from the normals at the vertices. The result is you get a "soft" transition from triangle to triangle.

If you want to keep the edges (hard transition) then you must provide different normals for different triangles. IOW, each vertex as seen from the shader gets its own normal. Repeat the vertex for a different triangle, then set a different normal even for the same vertex.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is marked with `point-cloud-library` tag, I am presenting a solution using **PCL**.

### Flip normal towards viewpoint

**PCL** has a function [`flipNormalTowardsViewpoint`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/group__features.html#ga53df49d690e1cb76cd1f53495508bff1) where you provide a point, the corresponding normal, and a viewpoint to flip towards to.

The viewpoint is usually the camera position in global coordinates, but if you only have a snapshot of the scene, then the viewpoint becomes **(0,0,0)**.